# How to convert DateBox's date string into Date_SHORT("YYYY-MM-DD") format?

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, datebox

I use DateBox in Google App Script,  and got the value of DateBox `Sat Jul 20 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)`.
How can I convert it to just be `2013-07-20`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Utilities.formatDate(](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate%28Date,String,String%29)) function.